# Vertical Scrollbar on DataGrid is too tall

Tags: wpf

I have a DataGrid bound to some data inside the main window. When enough rows are added, the vertical Scrollbar appears as it should. However, it is too tall so that the bottom scroll button is not visible and the last row is cut off.

Here is a picture of a simplified example, with the scrollbar all the way down:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? I'm guessing it has something to do with `WrapPanel` not automatically adjusting its height the way I expect.

Here is the code:

> MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestScroll.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="450">

    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock 
                Text="TextBlock" 
                Width="400"
                Height="40"/>

        <DataGrid 
            x:Name="Control" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False" 
            HeadersVisibility="Column" 
            Width="400"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Binding="{Binding Factor}"
                    Header="Header">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </WrapPanel>

</Window>
```

> MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestScroll
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var Table = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();
            this.DataContext = Table;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                var row = new ViewModel();
                row.Symbol = i.ToString();
                row.Factor = decimal.Parse(row.Symbol) / 100;
                Table.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ViewModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestScroll
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _symbol;
        public string Symbol
        {
            get { return _symbol; }
            set
            {
                _symbol = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Symbol");
            }
        }

        private decimal _factor;
        public decimal Factor
        {
            get { return _factor; }
            set
            {
                _factor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Factor");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post the XAML code for DataGrid and its parent.

Comment: Yes, I will have to make a simplified example. There is too much code to post.

Comment: What matters is how the heights of `DataGrid` and its container are set, the other code should be irrelevant.

Comment: @kennyzx, I have a counterexample. I have isolated the problem, so I will edit and post the simple code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            .../>
    <DataGrid...>
    </DataGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

The modification is replacing WrapPanel with DockPanel and setting first Child's DockPanel.Dock="Top".

Comment: Yes, that does work. However, it does not answer my question about WrapPanel. I want to know why I cannot use a WrapPanel, which seemed like the natural choice for the actual application (even if I am wrong about that).

Comment: Unlike other controls, `DataGrid` auto grows out of the containing Grid to fit its content (if you are adding many rows). I had found this problem before. the fix is to set an explicit MaxHeight to the DataGrid, or bound its Height to the containing Grid. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6680526/815938 has several other solutions.