# Datagrid vertical scrollviewer display in groupbox with auto height

Tags: c#, wpf

Following my problem.

Setting all the Rows as **Auto**, the last groupbox exceeds the container.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        ...
    <GroupBox Header="Results" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
       <DataGrid x:Name="dgResults">
</Grid>
```

[image]

By setting the last as * the scrollbar appears, however if I expand the window the groupbox reaches the bottom.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
    <GroupBox Header="Results" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
       <DataGrid x:Name="dgResults">
</Grid>
```

[image]

[image]

How can I get auto groupbox size and a datagrid with a vertical scroolbar?

Comment: do something similar to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6680526/5605739)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using DockPanel which constrains its children.